# Gathering end user feedback on a mobile device

Tags: mobile, design-patterns, feedback

I would like to be able to solicit feedback (comments, suggestions, etc) from end users within my mobile business applications. I would expect the feedback to range from "I really love/hate this" to "The whatchmacallit is broken" to "can you please add the following feature(s)?". Does anyone have any real world examples or design patterns that they feel work well for this?

Comment: What sort of feedback (blog comments, or feedback about the app for support)? What options have you tried? Why have the various options you've tried not been appropriate? You need to give us *a lot* more detail to go on here as well as showing what initial research you've done so we don't give you an option you've already tried out. (I assume you *have* tried some options already?)

Comment: This would be application related but the user may not need support (e.g. indicating they love or hate the app, asking general questions etc). I haven't tried anything in the mobile space as of yet. Whatever I come up with is going to be a standard enterprise wide solution and teams are already chomping at the bit to get a design. I do plan on doing user testing but I was hoping to get a shove in the right direction first.

Comment: @superduperfly Can you clarify the writing in your question to be more explicit? Specifically, what are your design constraints? What are your goals? Have you seen any other feedback form used in another app that is **not** good for your usage, and why? A better question will yield a better answer.

Comment: I suspect I am making this overly complicated. Basically what I am asking is if there are best practices and/or good examples of "contact us" forms for mobile devices. I have never used such a form on a mobile device; I don't believe I have ever even seen one. Does that clear it up?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are discussing feedback about the quality of your application (and you were vague, so this is in doubt), then you need to have hierarchal feedback. That means that a user should be able to give two-click feedback (Thumbs up/down, Submit), three-click feedback (THumbs up, Select stock response from list, Submit), and written feedback (Thumbs up, Select response, add comments, submit). They need to be able to be done at any step and still have given you a useful response that you can use. If you force them to provide complete feedback with a written response every time you will find you get very little feedback at all. If you prevent them from providing a written response when they have a complex issue you've also inconvenienced them and reduced the quality of your responses.

Also valuable is opt-in automated metrics. What features of the application did they use the most? How often do they open the app? What task is most likely to cause them to leave the app? This type of automated feedback can be very valuable, but make sure it is opt-in to avoid privacy concerns.